# Incorporating a Markdown Editor in a Userscript

Tags: css, uri, userscripts, tampermonkey, markdowndeep

I am trying to add [markdowndeep](https://github.com/toptensoftware/MarkdownDeep) as a part of a userscript I am designing. Unfortunately, Tampermonkey uses the old way of handling @Resources, and returns a base64 encoded data URI when `GM_getResourceURL` is called.

But trying to work with this (unfortunately this is for a site that requires a login).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Steamgifts Giveaway Improvement
// @version         2.5
// @namespace       http://indie-elitist.blogspot.ca/
// @description     Automates and streamlines commenting while entering giveaway.
// @match           http://www.steamgifts.com/*
// @include         http://www.steamgifts.com/*
// @grant           GM_getValue
// @grant           GM_setValue
// @grant           GM_deleteValue
// @grant           GM_listValues
// @grant           GM_getResourceText
// @grant           GM_getResourceURL
// @grant           GM_addStyle
// @require         https://raw.github.com/domchristie/to-markdown/master/src/to-markdown.js
// @resource        MarkdownDeepLib         https://raw.github.com/toptensoftware/markdowndeep/master/MarkdownDeepJS/MarkdownDeepLib.min.js
// @resource        mdd_styles              https://raw.github.com/toptensoftware/markdowndeep/master/MarkdownDeepJS/mdd_styles.css
// @resource        mdd_ajax_loader         https://raw.github.com/toptensoftware/markdowndeep/master/MarkdownDeepJS/mdd_ajax_loader.gif
// @resource        mdd_gripper             https://raw.github.com/toptensoftware/markdowndeep/master/MarkdownDeepJS/mdd_gripper.png
// @resource        mdd_modal_background    https://raw.github.com/toptensoftware/markdowndeep/master/MarkdownDeepJS/mdd_modal_background.png
// @resource        mdd_toolbar             https://raw.github.com/toptensoftware/markdowndeep/master/MarkdownDeepJS/mdd_toolbar.png
// @resource        mdd_help                https://raw.github.com/toptensoftware/markdowndeep/master/MarkdownDeepJS/mdd_help.htm
// ==/UserScript==


    var cssTxt = GM_getResourceText("mdd_styles");
    cssTxt = cssTxt.replace(/url\(.?mdd_ajax_loader\.gif.?\);/g,        'url(' + GM_getResourceURL('mdd_ajax_loader') + ')');
    cssTxt = cssTxt.replace(/url\(.?mdd_gripper\.png.?\);/g,            'url(' + GM_getResourceURL('mdd_gripper') + ')');
    cssTxt = cssTxt.replace(/url\(.?mdd_modal_background\.png.?\);/g,   'url(' + GM_getResourceURL('mdd_modal_background') + ')');
    cssTxt = cssTxt.replace(/url\(.?mdd_toolbar\.png.?\);/g,            'url(' + GM_getResourceURL('mdd_toolbar') + ')');
    GM_addStyle(cssTxt);

    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptTag.innerHTML = GM_getResourceText('MarkdownDeepLib');
    $('head').append(scriptTag);

    $('textarea#body').addClass('mdd_editor').MarkdownDeep({ help_location: decodeURIComponent(GM_getResourceURL('mdd_help')), disableTabHandling:true });
```

How would I ever use this in conjecture with `html` files, as in the case of `mdd_help.htm`?

But more pertinently, I have been completely unable to even get the images to work. Chrome is giving me a `"Invalid property value."`, in that "Inspect Element>CSS window", for (among others):
`url(data:image/png;base64,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) width:20px`